# image_tag in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have used image_tag in ruby on rails application for two different images, and now I want to specify different CSS properties for each image. I only have one img { } tag available. So, how can I do that?

Comment: Apply `id` or `class` to each `img` and using CSS styling from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`AssetTagHelper#image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) is defined as:

```
def image_tag(source, options = {})
  options = options.symbolize_keys
  check_for_image_tag_errors(options)
  skip_pipeline = options.delete(:skip_pipeline)

  options[:src] = resolve_image_source(source, skip_pipeline)

  if options[:srcset] && !options[:srcset].is_a?(String)
    options[:srcset] = options[:srcset].map do |src_path, size|
      src_path = path_to_image(src_path, skip_pipeline: skip_pipeline)
      "#{src_path} #{size}"
    end.join(", ")
  end

  options[:width], options[:height] = extract_dimensions(options.delete(:size)) if options[:size]
  tag("img", options)
end
```

See there the options argument, if you pass a src, a srcset, width and/or options they'll be handled by the method itself, and afterwards whatever your trying to build will be passed to the helper method [`tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7bfc79ec9bb054b97b2f961a75f8c789999b68dc/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L235):

```
def tag(name = nil, options = nil, open = false, escape = true)
  if name.nil?
    tag_builder
  else
    "<#{name}#{tag_builder.tag_options(options, escape) if options}#{open ? ">" : " />"}".html_safe
  end
end
```

So, if you need to specify CSS rules, being inline or through a class then you can add them as the options in your image tag, as the tag method will add each of them within the rendered "img" HTML tag.

```
<%= image_tag 'image', class: 'class', id: 'identifier', style: 'width: 360px; height: 280px' %>
```

Becomes

```
<img class="class" id="identifier" style="width: 360px; height: 280px" src="image">
```